# updating a nested dictionary using two other dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an nested dictionary which I am looking to update using two dictionaries. The empty dictionary which I am looking to populate is as below:-

```
master_config_skeleton = {
"ingestion_config":
    {
    "location":{}, 
    "start_sequence":{}, 
    "datafeed":
        {
        "t04047":
            {
            "validation":
                {
                "triple_check":{},
                "record_count_validation":{}
                }, 
            "date_pattern":{}, 
            "cdc_config": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One of dictionaries which holds the path of traversal looks like this.

```
    traversal_path_dict = {
        'cdc_config': "['ingestion_config']['datafeed']['t04047']['cdc_config']",
        'datafeed': "['ingestion_config']['datafeed']",
        'date_pattern': "['ingestion_config']['datafeed']['t04047']['date_pattern']",
        'ingestion_config': "['ingestion_config']",
        'location': "['ingestion_config']['location']",
        'record_count_validation': "['ingestion_config']['datafeed']['t04047']['validation']['record_count_validation']",
        'start_sequence': "['ingestion_config']['start_sequence']",
        't04047': "['ingestion_config']['datafeed']['t04047']",
        'triple_check': "['ingestion_config']['datafeed']['t04047']['validation']['triple_check']",
        'validation': "['ingestion_config']['datafeed']['t04047']['validation']"}
```

And the other dictionary which actually holds the data looks as below:-

```
master_data_dict = {   'cdc_config': {   'active_table': 'db_b2b_curated_flexcab_active.t04047',
                      'custom_cdc_query': '',
                      'delete_filters': '["","",""]',
                      'delete_query': '',
                      'history_table': 'db_b2b_curated_flexcab_historical.t04047_historical',
                      'key_cols': '[INVC_ARGT_ID, BILL_CYCLE_EFF_DT, '
                                  'BILL_CYCLE_CD]',
                      'start_date_col': '[BILL_CYCLE_EFF_DT]',
                      'update_ts_col': 'bill_cycle_end_dt'},
    'date_pattern': {'ord_end_dt': '%d.%m.%Y', 'ord_sta_dt': '%d.%m.%Y'},
    'ingestion_config': {   'app': 'Replicator',
                            'feed_id': 2382,
                            'hdfs_home_dir': '/data/b2b',
                            'seq_type': 'SEQUENCE',
                            'source': 'FLEXCAB'},
    'location': {   'base_dir': '/home/sfxuser/B2B_DATALAKE/data/b2b/land/FLEXCAB',
                    'error_dir': 'Error',
                    'input_dir': 'Input',
                    'unzipped_dir': 'src'},
    'record_count_validation': {   'footer': 'N',
                                   'header': 'N',
                                   'rec_cnt_pos_ctl': '0:10'},
    'start_sequence': {'initial_seq_id': '00000001', 'length': 8},
    't04047': {   'cdc': 'N',
                  'config_path': '/apps/b2b_datalake/legacy/FLEXCAB/cfg/CSV/t04047.csv',
                  'format': 'fixedwidth'},
    'triple_check': {   'file_count': 3,
                        'file_extensions': '[zip, ctl, eot]',
                        'file_pattern': 'FLEXCAB_B2B_T04047_O_(<batch_seq>)_*'},
    'validation': {'file_date_format': '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}}
```

As you can notice, not all the keys in the dictionary which I am looking to populate have values. The 2nd dictionary is basically a pandas data frame generated from an excel which holds key value pairs. All the sheets of the excel workbook are stored in a separate list:-

```
sheets = ['ingestion_config', 'location', 'start_sequence', 'datafeed', 't04047', 'validation', 'triple_check', 'record_count_validation', 'date_pattern', 'cdc_config']
```

What I've tried so far:-

```
for sheet in sheets:
    master_config_skeleton[traversal_path_dict[sheet]].update(master_data_dict[sheet])
```

but because of the square brackets qualifying the values, I am getting a key error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the .get method? If not [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is a link to the python docs which returns None if no key is found, this will prevent the key error.